# Apply SVG clipPath to geometry

Tags: android, svg, androidsvg

The library I'm using to render SVG on Android doesn't support `clipPath`. The [workaround](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg/issues/94) is to "apply the clip path to your objects so their shapes are physically clipped". What is the algorithm for converting an SVG containing `clipPath` elements to an equivalent geometry with no instances of `clipPath`?

Comment: Depends on the shape. If you clip a rect with a rect you'll get a smaller rect for instance. The algorithm for generating the shape of an arbitrary shape clipped by another arbitrary shape would likely be too broad to answer here.

Comment: I am the author of AndroidSVG.  When I made that suggestion, I meant that you should use your vector editor to make this change.  All editors should be able to do this. There should be no need to do it yourself.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks; I have reposed the question at [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82908/apply-svg-clippath-to-geometry).